# Solutions to differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

The geodesic equation of a particle is described as
$$\left(1-\frac{2\mu}{r}\right)\dot{t}=k \tag{1}$$
$$\left(1-\frac{2\mu}{r}\right)^{-1}\ddot{r}+\frac{\mu c^2}{r^2}\dot{t}-\left(1-\frac{2 \mu}{r}\right)^{-2}\frac{\mu}{r^2}\dot{r}^2-r(\dot{\theta}^2+sin^2\theta\dot{\phi}^2)=0 \tag{2}$$

$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{2}{r}\dot{r}\dot{\theta}-sin\theta cos\theta\dot{\phi}^2=0 \tag{3}$$
$$r^2sin^2\theta\dot{\phi}=h \tag{4}$$
where $r$ is the radial coordinate, $\theta$ denotes the angle to the z axis ,$\phi$ is the polar angle, $k, \mu$ and $h$ are some constants. $\dot{t}$ denotes the derivative of t with respect to some parameter $\sigma$.

The solution to (3) is $\theta=\pi/2$.

So the third term of (3) vanishes but how do the first and second term yield zero?

Comment: Are you looking to integrate the first two terms?

Comment: Hem, what it the derivative of a constant ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Ok that makes sense now... The first thing that popped up in my mind was if $f(x)=0$, then $f^{-1}(x)$ is not necessarily zero....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\theta=\pi/2$ is definitely **one** of the solutions (or at least, a part of it). However, this is a differential equation, and differential equations always have an infinite number of solutions based on their initial conditions. In this case, you don't even have enough equations to do that.

You have three unknown functions: $r(\sigma)$, $\theta(\sigma)$ and $\phi(\sigma)$, so you need **three** differential equations, and also initial values and derivatives for each of the coordinates (6 numbers for initial condition). Only then you can actually get a specific solution.